# Cannot find debug adapter to "react native"

Tags: android, react-native

Why can I not run react-native on android simulator with vscode? I added in configurations at launch.json:

```
{"name": "Debug Android",
  "program": "${workspaceRoot}/.vscode/launchReactNative.js",
  "type": "reactnative",
  "request": "launch",
  "platform": "android",
  "sourceMaps": true,
  "outDir": "${workspaceRoot}/.vscode/.react",
  "trace": "verbose"},
```

[image]

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: @RizwanAhmedShivalli I am trying to run the react-native on an android simulator/android phone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Running react-native on simulator**

step 1. Keep the simulator running from android studio.

step 2. open terminal on the project folder.

step 3. run `react-native run-android`

the app will launch on simulator

**Running react-native on device**

step 1. Enable Debugging over USB

step  2. Plug in your device via USB

step 3. Check that your device is properly connecting to ADB

```
List of devices attached
emulator-5554 offline   # Google emulator
14ed2fcc device         # Physical device
```

Seeing device in the right column means the device is connected. You must have only one device connected at a time.

step 4. open terminal on the project folder.
step 5. Run your app

```
react-native run-android
```

the app will launch on physical device

If you get a "bridge configuration isn't available" error, see [Using adb reverse.](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device#method-1-using-adb-reverse-recommended)